# Angular 1.5 collapsed table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to make a collapsable table row, nested inside of the row is a table. My collapsing function works, as it allows the user to collapse once they execute **ctrl.toggle()** however, my issue is that every single row collapses instead of a specific one, I have looked through other blogs and posts in Stack Overflow, but none of them helped with my question. I will appreciate any feedback as I am new in coding and I want to learn more. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<table>
       <thead>
           <tr >
              <th >Host Name</th>
               <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr class="hover-pointer accordion-toggle" ng-click="syh.toggle()" ng-repeat-start="value in syh.data" >

                      <td> {{value.host_name}}</td>
                      <td> empty   </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="syh.show_details==true" class="slide-toggle-js" >
                      <td colspan="2" >
                          <div ng-if="syh.show_details==true" class="toggle-me" >

                              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover-alt text-center">
                                  <thead>
                                  <tr class="blue-bg">
                                      <th > Service</th>
                                      <th >Status</th>

                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody ng-cloak>
                                  <tr ng-repeat="value in value.service " >
                                      <td>{{value.service}}</td>
                                      <td>{{value.status}}</td>

                                  </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                              </table>

                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

**JS**

```
  ctrl.toggle = function(){
    if(ctrl.show_details == true){
      ctrl.show_details = false
    }else if (ctrl.show_details == false) {
        ctrl.show_details = true
    }
  }

  ctrl.data =[
    {host_name:'cadsapp-ch2-p7.steel.cloud.comcast.net', service:[{service:'/app partition',status:0},{service:'/app partition',status:0},{service:'/app partition',status:0},{service:'/app partition',status:0}]},
    {host_name:'stuff', service:[{service:'/app',status:0}]},
    {host_name:'stuffing', service:[{service:'/partition',status:0}]}

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-if="syh.show_details==true"` that will show/hide every row.

The `show_details` should be an array and set to true or false depending on the row id:

```
<tr ... ng-if="syh.show_details[i]==true" ...>
```

Also, `toggle` function should have a parameter:

```
ctrl.toggle = function(i) {
    ctrl.show_details[i] == !ctrl.show_details[i];
}
```

Comment: that didn't work even though I have used ctrl.show_details = [] or setting it to ctrl.show_details = null; as the initial values

Comment: initialization should set the value to all values of the ctrl.show_details array